# ADMM Updates for $ {L}_{1} $ Minimization with Constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, proximal-operators

I am trying to minimize and $L_1$ problem with inequality constraints:

\begin{equation}
||Ax - b||_1 \;\text{subject to}\; x > c
\end{equation}
I believe the way to formulate this with ADMM is:

\begin{equation}
\text{minimize}\; f(x) + g(z) \\
\text{subject to:}\;  Ax - b - z = 0
\end{equation}

where $g(z)=|z|$ and $f(x)$ is and indicator function that is 0 when x > c and $\infty$ otherwise. The update steps are then:
\begin{align}
x&=argmin_x \; f(x) + 0.5\rho ||Ax - b - z + u||^2 \\
z&=S_{1/\rho}(Ax-b+u) \\
u&= u + Ax - z - b
\end{align}

Where $S_{1/p}$ is the $L_1$ proximal operator. The x-update is the only one that differs from standard $L_1$ minimization with ADMM. To solve for the best x-update you can solve a quadratic program:
\begin{equation}
\text{let}\;d=b+z-u \\
\text{min} ||Ax -d||_2^2= x^TA^TAx - 2x^TA^Td + d^Td \\
\text{subject to:}\;x > c
\end{equation}

Solving the problem this way does not yield a valid solution. I am using the ADMM solvers directly from the [stanford website](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/admm/) for solving the QP and modifying the L1 problem. Is there something wrong with my formulation? Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not transform it into Linear Programming (LP) Problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you omitted the step-size $\rho$ in the algorithm scheme.
The augmented lagrangian of that problem has the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_p(x,z,u)=f(x)+g(z)+\langle u,Ax-z-b\rangle+\frac{\rho}{2}\Vert Ax-z-b\Vert^2_2
\end{equation}

If the algorithm doesn't converge, you might want to reformulate the problem with $\rho$  smaller than 1.

Comment: I agree that the augmented Lagrangian is missing. However, the ADMM should converge for any $\rho>0$.

Comment: I've edited the post to show $\rho$ but this does not effect the x-update step since it is only a scalar multiple.